# calculate the amount of memory used by a particular process in linux

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I'm writing a program to trace every system call called by child process and determine the exact memory use of it(excluding sharing memory).

here's my plan.

let child process ptraced by father process,

if child process make system calls, father process will recieve SIGTRAP,

then get syscall id with ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child_pid, 4*ORIG_EAX, NULL).

when the id equals to SYS_brk, SYS_sbrk, SYS_mmap2, SYS_mmap, SYS_mremap, SYS_munmap ,

i am able to get parameters of the call and calculate the amount of memory use.

but it troubles me that

1. I'm not sure how to calculate.
2. SYS_mmap2 has over 6 parameters, how should I get it?

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. parsing the output of `ps`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, At least you should use a library such as `libprocps4-dev` and not read the output of ps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the memory use for a process of pid 1234, I suggest reading sequentially and parsing the `/proc/1234/maps` or `/proc/1234/smaps` pseudo-file. Other files under `/proc/1234/` could be also relevant (e.g. `/proc/1234/statm` and `/proc/1234/status`)

From inside a process, you can read `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/smaps` (and e.g. `/proc/self/statm` and `/proc/self/status`).

Read the [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) man page for details.

There is also the [pmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) command

Comment: [stack] returned by pmap is what I want.

Comment: `[stack]` is also inside `/proc/1234/maps` which `pmap` actually reads.